# Git clone on an ovh host server

Tags: ssh, git, clone

I want to do a git-clone from an SSH connection, on an ovh host-server, but it does not work. I'm using a terminal from my Mac.

Here's the command I entered:

```
git clone ssh://me@example.com/www/
```

(and all variations `/.Git` `/www/.git`, `/www/.git/` ... )

This is the message that I invariably get:

```
fatal: '/www': unable to chdir or not a git archive fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Moreover, the command

```
git clone "ssh://git@ftp.example.com/ ~/forumdesthinktanks.git"
```

Responded with:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
git@ftp.example.com's password:
```

While the FTP password is correct.

Finally, the commands:

```
git clone ssh://forumdesy@forumdesthinktanks.fr/.Git
```

And this:

```
git clone ssh://git@forumdesthinktanks.fr/ ~/forumdesthinktanks.git
```

Do not work (until the terminal's time out).

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard for me to see what you're doing with the way you formatted it, but here's some things to remember when cloning:

1. It's CaSE SenSiTivE.
2. You want to use `git clone ssh://username@host.org/path/to/repository/.git` assuming default configurations. (it could also be that the directory with the repository ends in .git, so then you wouldn't have the /.git at the end)
3. Make sure you have at least read permissions to the repository.

You might be doing this so that it doesn't become a link in your post, but you shouldn't have spaces before or after the /s. (really no spaces at all except in certain conditions)

Comment: Thank you for your response? It seems I don't have the right permission. Best, Newben

Comment: @Newben You can check if you have proper permissions by sshing into the server normally, going to the enclosing directory and using `ls -l`

Comment: Hello Everybody, you're absolutely right ! I went to an ssh connectoin, made a 'pwd', and I had the right path.  I put in my git-clone command : 'git clone ssh :/ / forumdesy@forumdesthinktanks.fr /'Path' and it worked. Thanks a lot, Newben